# Object origin is not moving in pose mode

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, objects, armature

[image: object at 0th frame]I animated a man walk cycle for 180 frames in pose mode
[image: origin at same position]
Then I switched to object mode and played the animation, but the origin stays in the same position and it's not moving with the object.

I don't know how to fix the problem.

In object mode also the same problem existed
[image: object mode origin]

Comment: If you animate the bones that are within the armature object, the origin is not supposed to move, the origin will move if you move the armature object itself in Object mode, but if you want to move the object itself it's probably better to parent it to an empty and move the empty instead, this way you won't add the object keyfarmes to the bone keyframes

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.

Comment: I parented the armature to the model, but when I do some changes or moved the model, the origin does not tend to move with the model.